# What precautions should I take when upgrading or replacing a CPU?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, intel-core-i7

I have an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHZ. I was just considering upgrade options for gaming, and I'm not even sure if it's possible.

- If I get one, doesn't it need to match the slot type on my motherboard?
- How do I check my kind of motherboard without opening up my computer?

Answer (score 1):

The E8400 is an LGA755 Socket CPU, you can put any LGA755 CPU in that motherboard, although an E8400 is an excellent CPU, they can overclock great and really do give you good gains.

If you are looking for a quad core then the Q9400 is a decent upgrade:
http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=CP-270-IN&groupid=701&catid=6&subcat=567

As said in the other post CPUz will help you get information about your system.

Comment: It's not quite true that you can put any X-type cpu in any X-type socket.  You should always check your motherboard's compatibility list (and possible firmware revision) first. But generally most motherboards of a given socket can accept most cpus of that type, socket type is the first step to take.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the newly purchased CPU works for your motherboard. To do that you can use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

After you find that, then just look up online what CPUs are compatible.